# Cleave.js pattern DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: javascript, cleave

How to add a trailing dot to Cleave.js date pattern (DD.MM.YYYY.)?

So valid input would be: **04.05.2023.**

```
new Cleave('.my-input', {
    date: true,
    datePattern: ['Y', 'm', 'd'],
    delimiter: '.'
});


// outputs: DD.MM.YYYY - without the final dot
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with only cleave.js.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `'.'` to the end of `datePattern`.

```
 new Cleave('.my-input', {
        date: true,
        datePattern: ['D', 'M', 'Y', '.'],
        delimiter: '.'
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work.